# How to simplify this problem?

Tags: recursive-algorithms

Please give me some hints about this problem.

Express the sum

$S = \binom{99}{33} + \binom{100}{34} + \ldots + \binom{200}{134}$

in this form

$S = \binom{}{} - \binom{}{}$

I try using the following relation

$\binom{r}{k} = \frac{r}{k}\binom{r-1}{k-1}$

then

$\binom{r}{k} = \binom{r-1}{k-1} - \frac{k-r}{k}\binom{r-1}{k-1}$

Am I on the right track? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm quite curious about where this problem is from: is there anything special about the numbers $99, 33, 200, 134$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the hockey stick identity
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=r}^{n} \binom{i}{r}=\binom{n+1}{r+1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Your sum can be written as
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=99}^{200} \binom{i}{66}=\sum_{i=66}^{200} \binom{i}{66}-\sum_{i=66}^{98} \binom{i}{66}=\color{red}{\binom{201}{67}-\binom{99}{67}}.
\end{eqnarray*}